# For given array of pairs of two numbers, count pairs in which first element is bigger and second one is smaller

Tags: arrays, sorting

I'm trying to implement this in my program, namely we have given array of K pairs, where each pair is in form (i,j) and i<=N, j<=M, N,M<=1000, and K<=N*M.

Now for each pair we want to count pairs in which the first element is strictly bigger and the second one is strictly less, for example if our pair is: (2,3), we want to count the pair (4,1), but not the pair (1,2) because 1 is less than 2.

Is this possible to do in O(N*M) time complexity?

Comment: *Is this possible to do in O(NxM) time complexity?* Your description of the algorithm is already in O(NxM) for K <= NxM

Comment: Yes, but we don't really need to do brute-force for all K combinations of pairs

Comment: Well, there is no way to not iterate through all the elements since that is basically your question